# Nodejs Express cross domain cookies neither receiving from react app nor setting the cookie

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

I am trying to make simple authentication with node js and react js where I am sending post request from react to node so the request is cross domain and in node js req.cookie returning blank object.
response of this request is

```
a: "hii"
b: {}
```

Here is a node js code that i am using to test cookies :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin:"http://localhost.com:3000",
    methods:["POST","GET","PUT","DELETE"],
    credentials:true
}));
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
    secret: 'street',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    proxy: true,
    cookie: {
        sameSite:'none',
        secure:true
    }
}));

app.post('/users/userInfo',function (req,res) {
    res.cookie('nm','h').send({
        b:req.cookies,
        a:'hii'
    });
});

app.listen(3001);
```

Here is react code that sending request to the above code :

```
axios.post(url, data, {
    headers: headers,
    withCredentials:true
});
```